# Convert Tableau Calculated Field to SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, tableau-api

Need help converting a calculated field from Tableau to SQL

The Tableau field is:

```
COUNTD(IF DATEDIFF('hour',[Created Date],[Closed Date])<24 then [Case Number] END)*100/COUNTD([Case Number])
```

Need that converted to SQL. Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Sorry someone else was able to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR,[Created Date],[Closed Date]) < 24
                           THEN [Case Number]
                           ELSE NULL
                           END)*100/COUNT(DISTINCT [Case Number])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that case number is never `null`, you could do this with `avg()`:

```
avg(case when closed_date < dateadd(day, 1, created_date) then 100.0 else 0 end)
```

Else, you need a little more logic:

```
avg(case 
    when case_number is null then null
    when closed_date < dateadd(day, 1, created_date) then 100.0 
    else 0 
end)
```

Finally, *if* `COUNTD` means "count distinct" and you do have duplicate case numbers, then we are back to the original division technique:

```
100.0
    * count(distinct case when closed_date < dateadd(day, 1, created_date) then case_number end)
    / count(distinct case_number)
```